# Efficient search based on if a datetime value falls in a range

Tags: c#, dictionary, search

UPDATED CONCISE QUESTION

I have an object which holds a list of DateTime values. This is the list of holidays and also the working hours in a day.

Item.cs

```
class Item
{
    public int SourceId { get; set; }
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> Holidays { get; set; }
}
```

If not for Holidays we can hold the list of items in a dictionary with the Tuple as the key.

Requirements

There will be one item that will match the criteria (because there is a default item to handle the case when no item matches)

The properties are meant to change every now and then

1) Is it possible to get hash code for such an object including the Holidays property.

2) If not a dictionary, how to design a data structure for such a search with optimal time complexity

**Original Unclear Post**

I implemented a dictionary with a tuple as the key, it has worked till now very well.

Existing Dictionary key

```
Tuple<int, int, int, string>
```

Existing Search Method

```
var item = default(item);
_dictinary.TryGetValue(new Tuple(1,1,1,""), out item);
return item;
```

because the search parameters were fixed.

However now a new requirement has come up such that the tuple items are dynamic ie the search parameters are variable in number. I tried to keep the number fixed by assuming there will always be a maximum number of search parameters but then I hit the wall when another search parameter of type date range came as a requirement. This meant I cannot have a dictionary as the underlying data structure.

Therefore I needed to know what kind of data structure would some one consider to keep the search as efficient as possible when there are multiple criteria with something like date range.

For completeness, let me say the new search parameter is a date range and called Holiday. ie I need to match if today is in the date range of that Holiday including other paramters

Holiday.cs

```
public class Holiday
{
    public List<Day> Days{ get; set; }
}
```

where Day is a wrapper of DateTime denoting a day in a year.

Summary
 Combination of
SourceId(int), DestinationId(int), ChannelId(int), Username(int), (IsTodayHoliday (Holiday-DateRanges)) should find one the items in the collection uniquely

I cannot use a hash of an object because the search parameter object is a mutable one with date ranges, and the ranges are not necessarily contiguous, at the least I don't know how to get a hash for such an object

I completely understand that a matching algorithm is required and as I have mentioned above I definitely need to change my data structure and dictionary is not suitable. My question is very specific to the design of the data structure to improve the search complexity.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of both the data points you are trying to search and the type of query being made to search them?

Comment: I have a strong feeling you are miss-using the dictionary as primary structure used for your search. You probably need to use `SearchParams` as an input to the custom match predicate of your objects (instead of using dictionary's match-by-key)

Comment: _the design of the data structure to improve the search complexity_ did you wanted to say **efficiency** instead of **complexity**?

Comment: @Dusan yes, efficiency , I meant time complexity

Comment: Create whatever object you want and use a  [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) for the key.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `dictionary` can be used to match-by-key which is not so flexible,
I suggest you use normal list and linq:

```
class Item
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    string s;
    List<Day> days;
}

class SearchParams
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    string s;
    Day d1;
    Day d2;
}

// Populate items
var items = new List<Item>();
items.Add(...);

// Search items
var par = new SearchParams { ... };
var matches = items.Where(x=> 
    x.a == par.a &&
    x.b == par.b &&
    x.c == par.c &&
    x.s == par.s &&
    x.days.Any(d >= par.d1 && d <= par.d2)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, could you please explain how this tries to improve the search time complexity. When the params were fixed, dictionary was doing a great job of keeping the search O(1). This will drastically reduce the search speed

Comment: @SrivathsaHarishVenkataramana yes - range searches are much harder than single item search... Unless you want to invest a lot into proper indexing linear search is easy to prove reliable alternative.

Comment: Are you expecting only one match? Please, be more specific, show us some example so we do not have to speculate about your intent...